# ReferenceError: documentFragmentChildren is not defined

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic4, progressive-web-apps

I am writing a PWA Ionic 4 app to subscribe and show Firebase push notifications. Everything about it works just fine. For example, I am able to install the app in chrome browser (meaning the PWA part works well) and I can subscribe and receive messages when they are published. In my Firebase service file, I make a toast using the following function.

```
  async makeToast(message) {
    console.log(message);
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: message,
      duration: 5000,
      position: 'top',
      showCloseButton: true,
      closeButtonText: 'dismiss'
    });
    toast.present();
}
```

But there is something wrong about it since I see the toast coming up but with an empty body (message). I can see in the console that the message is not empty. But there is this error

```
 ReferenceError: documentFragmentChildren is not defined
    at r (common-es2015.edd3f5ddbecdc7d4b97d.js:1)
    at b.render (90-es2015.a511a29a06087ce2ae17.js:1)
    at pe (main-es2015.82bfa6fe443f99f03efa.js:1)
    at Array.o (main-es2015.82bfa6fe443f99f03efa.js:1)
    at D (main-es2015.82bfa6fe443f99f03efa.js:1)
    at x (main-es2015.82bfa6fe443f99f03efa.js:1)
    at a.invoke (polyfills-es2015.a5a02c8969fb7b2904df.js:1)
    at t.run (polyfills-es2015.a5a02c8969fb7b2904df.js:1)
    at polyfills-es2015.a5a02c8969fb7b2904df.js:1
    at a.invokeTask (polyfills-es2015.a5a02c8969fb7b2904df.js:1)
r @ common-es2015.edd3f5ddbecdc7d4b97d.js:1
```

To run the code, I do

```
ionic build --prod
http-server ./www -o
```

Interestingly, when I do `ionic serve` the toast works fine but PWA and Firebase breaks.

Comment: The code you showed doesn't show any immediately obvious interaction with Firebase to me. Can you make sure the question includes enough information to reproduce the problem? See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My problem is not the Firebase part, I mentioned that so say why I cannot use `ionic serve`

Comment: what does it say when you dont build production?

Comment: I would double check that your constructing the ion-toast element correctly.

Comment: I also tested `ionic build`. It resulted in getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete node_modules folder, package-lock.json.
2. Run

> npm cache clean --force

3. Install packages again by running:

> npm install

This solution helped me with the same problem.

Comment: Sadly this does not work for me since the compilation step to es2015 seems to be broken, perhaps the ionic team can help solve it in this issue: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19442